# Deserializing XML File with multiple element attributes - attributes are not deserializing

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Using C# .Net 4 -- XML Sample (Real sample has 6 attributes)

```
<TestXML>
  <TestElement attr1="MyAttr" attr2="1" DateAdded="">25</TestElement>
</TestXML>
```

For my class definition I have the following:

```
public class TestXML() {
   public TestXML() {}

   public int TestElement {get; set;}
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string attr1 {get; set;}
   [XmlAttribute]
   public string attr2 {get; set;}
   [XmlIgnore]
   public DateTime DateAdded {get; set;}
   [XmlAttribute("DateAdded")]
   public string dateadded {
      get{ return (DateAdded == null ? "" : DateAdded.ToString();}
      set{ if(!value.Equals("")) DateAdded = DateTime.Parse(value);}
   }
}
```

Now the code to deserialize:

```
string xml = "<TestXML><TestElement attr1=\"MyAttr\" attr2=\"1\" DateAdded=\"\">26</TestElement></TestXML>"
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml)) {
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXML));
   TestXML myxml = (TestXML)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

Now the result we get is(viewing object in VS):

```
myxml
  attr1         |  null
  attr2         |  null
  TestElement   |  25
```

At a complete loss as to why the attributes will not deserialize.

Comment: `<TestElement>` refers **only** to `public int TestElement {get;set;}`

Comment: The goal of this question is to get the code to work the xml is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To do that you need two levels:

```
[XmlRoot("TestXML")]
public class TestXml {
    [XmlElement("TestElement")]
    public TestElement TestElement { get; set; }
}

public class TestElement {
    [XmlText]
    public int Value {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string attr1 {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string attr2 {get;set;}
}
```

Note that the `> 26 <` may cause problems too (whitespace); you may need that to be a string instead of an int.

Comment: Corrected the spaces around the value, reformatted it to the two classes however the reference variable on the first class comes back null;

Comment: @pyTeaParty Simply change: `public TestElement {get;set;}` to: `public TestElement TestElement {get;set;}`.

Comment: Ahh, forgot about matching the element name, so yes the two class is the solution on my bigger test that I have thank you so much @Eve

Comment: Not a problem @MarcGravell I find this site to be very helpful in the various issues I run across.  My first time posting a question here.  Now that I have an account I can contribute more.

Comment: I have found this pattern to be very helpful when elements contain leading and/or trailing spaces. Deserializer will use the 'set' method to remove spaces, or do other logic you need.
  // backing value
  private string _attr1;
  // visible value
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string attr1
  {
    get { return _attr1; }
    set { _attr1 = value.Trim(); }
  }

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the attributes on `TestElement` while they should be on `TestXML`. Example:

```
@"<TestXML attr1=""MyAttr"" attr2=""1"">
      <TestElement>26</TestElement>
  </TestXML>"
```

Comment: The XML is correct in it's formatting I suspect the issue is in the class definition just don't see what needs to be done as other examples show the same setup except with only one attribute.

Comment: @pyTeaParty The XML is correct syntactically, but we don't know whether he wanted the code to adapt to it or to understand why it didn't work. I thought that pointing out how the XML should be for his code to work would be useful.

Comment: Thanks trying to get the code to work with the XML is what I trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran a test serializing/deserializing your object and it seems to work fine

Test:

```
TestXML obj = new TestXML{ attr1 = "Attrib1", attr2 = "Attrib2", DateAdded = DateTime.Now, TestElement = 44};

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXML));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\StackOverflow.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);
}

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\StackOverflow.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    TestXML myxml = (TestXML)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

all attributes deserialized ok.

Result:

[image]

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attr1="Attrib1" attr2="Attrib2" DateAdded="10/01/2013 9:46:23 a.m.">
  <TestElement>44</TestElement>
</TestXML>
```

Comment: Looking closer I see you serialize the object first.  Clearly the xml does not match so my class definition is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

As an additional note to the accepted answer.  Make sure the xml element doesn't contain a nil="true" attribute like this:

```
<TestXML>
  <TestElement attr1="MyAttr" attr2="1" DateAdded="" xsi:nil="true">25</TestElement>
</TestXML>
```

From my experience the deserializer won't deserialize attributes of an element marked as null (nil).