# Value field of deserialize xml has no value when using XmlAnyAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

This is the XML sample but using a different approach for defining the attributes:

```
<TestXML>
   <TestData attr1="MyAttr" attr2="1" DateAdded="">25</TestData>
</TestXML>
```

Now my class definitions:

```
public class TestXML() {
   [XmlElement("TestData")]
   public IntegerValue value {get; set;}
}

public class IntegerValue() {
   public int value {get; set;}
   [XmlAnyAttribute]
   public string[] XAttributes {get; set;}
}
```

Now the code to deserialize:

```
string xml = "<TestXML><TestData attr1=\"MyAttr\" attr2=\"1\" DateAdded=\"\">25</TestElement> </TestXML>"
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml)) {
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXML));
   TestXML myxml = (TestXML)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

Produces the following result:

```
myxml
   value     |  0
   XAttributes  {string[7]}
     [0] "MyAttr"
     [1] "1"
     [2] ""
```

The xml is formatted correctly.  Have not been able to get the value to deserialize using XMLAnyAttribute.  Would like to get the name along with the value of the attributes back but haven't found an example of that approach so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserializing XML File with multiple element attributes - attributes are not deserializing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245846/deserializing-xml-file-with-multiple-element-attributes-attributes-are-not-des)

Comment: Not a duplicate but a different example using the XmlAnyAttribute instead of defining each attribute.  This approach is simpler when dealing with unknown attributes of Xml you do not have control of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply change `string[] XAttributes` to `XmlAttribute[] XAttributes` this will return the whole attribute so you can access Name and Value

```
public class IntegerValue
{
   public int value {get; set;}

   [XmlAnyAttribute]
   public XmlAttribute[] XAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

My Test:

```
public class TestXML
{
    [XmlElement("TestData")]
    public IntegerValue value { get; set; }
}

public class IntegerValue
{
    public int value { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute[] XAttributes { get; set; }
}


XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestXML));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\StackOverflow.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    TestXML myxml = (TestXML)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note: The xml you posted is invalid, the closing tag of `TestData` is `TestElement` that wont work

```
<TestXML>
   <TestData attr1="MyAttr" attr2="1" DateAdded="">25</TestElement>
</TestXML>
```

it should be

```
<TestXML>
   <TestData attr1="MyAttr" attr2="1" DateAdded="">25</TestData>
</TestXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value property is not being set because you need to define it as XML text.  Try this:

```
public class IntegerValue() {
  [XmlText]
  public int value {get; set;}
  [XmlAnyAttribute]
  public string[] XAttributes {get; set;}
}
```

Note, its a c# convention to not include the string 'Attribute' in attribute decorations.  So it

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however XmlAny does not come as a valid decoration and in the case of XmlAnyAttribute it's the short name for XmlAnyAttributeAttribute.

Comment: XMLText decoratar is what is needed to get the element value back.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry about XmlAny...will change.