# XML deserialization using c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am having a problem about XML deserialization because of names of tags.

It's my XML (will be imported from the web each time program starts (of course, with different blablas and different count number))

```
<history xmlns:oslc_cm="blabla" oslc_cm:collref="blabla">
    <oslc_cm:totalCount>10</oslc_cm:totalCount>     
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
    <history rdf:resource="blabla"/>
</history>
```

I need the "blabla" parts. If the outer  had a different name, I would be able to deserialize the file, but here I don't know what to do since history class has the list of history class in it. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I know how to define classes to deserialize an XML file. I'm having a hard time about the name issue

Comment: Have you written any code for this yet?  You should be able to use the `XmlSerialization` class and define behaviors based on attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245846/deserializing-xml-file-with-multiple-element-attributes-attributes-are-not-des

Comment: Simply deserialize as (into) array of items (`history[]`), where each item has property `resource` (?) serialized as attribute. Not sure in `rfd:` part, therefore a comment.

Comment: The rfd: part should not hurt, you can still get it via XmlNode.Attributes["rdf:resource"].Value

Comment: This isn't valid XML, or it's just chopped out of a larger one - where's the namespace declaration for `rdf`? There should be an attribute `xmlns:rdf="..."`.  And you need to show some code and where you're stuck:  'I'm having a problem... because of names of tags' is far too vague.