# Deserialize To Object

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

I am trying to deserialize XML to C# object.

My XML is as:

```
<StaffingOrder xmlns='StaffinfOrderNamespace' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <OrderId idOwner="VMSAccess">
      <IdValue name='RequisitionID'>1</IdValue>
      <IdValue name='KellyBranch'>3319</IdValue>
   </OrderId>
</StaffingOrder>
```

My Class is as:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot("StaffingOrder")]
public class OrderId
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RequisitionID")]
    public int RequisitionID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "KellyBranch")]
    public int KellyBranch { get; set; }
}
```

My WCF Service contract is as:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadOrderDocument",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
 [XmlSerializerFormat]
 OrderId UploadOrderDocument(string hrXML);
```

I am trying to Deserialize as:

```
public OrderId UploadOrderDocument(string hrXMLString)
{

    OrderId orderId = new OrderId();

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(hrXMLString))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderId));
        orderId = (OrderId)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        var temp = orderId.RequisitionID;
    }

    return orderId;
}
```

I am not getting any error while deserializing, but not getting any value of `RequisitionID`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing XML File with multiple element attributes - attributes are not deserializing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245846/deserializing-xml-file-with-multiple-element-attributes-attributes-are-not-des)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes don't seem to bare much resemblance to the XML you're trying to deserialise.  If you were to create XML from the classes you've created, it would look something like this:

```
<StaffingOrder>
    <RequisitionID>1</RequisitionID>
    <KellyBranch>3319</KellyBranch>
</StaffingOrder>
```

What you want are classes that actually represent the XML structure:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "StaffinfOrderNamespace")]
public class StaffingOrder
{    
    public OrderId OrderId { get; set; }    
}

public class OrderId
{
    [XmlAttribute("idOwner")]
    public string IdOwner { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IdValue")]
    public List<IdValue> IdValues { get; set; }
}

public class IdValue
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MRsYm2) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually have is this object

```
public class OrderId
{
    [XmlElement]
    public IEnumerable<int> IdValue { get; set; }
}
```

ElementName does NOT work against the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this, one is changing your classes like Charles mentioned, the other is implement IXmlSerializable and implement your own serialization logic.

An additional advantage of IXmlSerializable is that if your XML structure changes somewhere along the way, you can change that implementation without necessarily  having to alter the structure of your classes.

Comment: Can you please help me with any example

Comment: There's a great article about that here on the code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly