# Deserializing an XML array with attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have to consume xml from a tool. In the xml is this part:

```
<profile>
  <details environment="sd98qlx" severity="critical">
    <detail unit="sec" value="12"/>
    <detail unit="sec" value="25"/>
    <detail unit="msec" value="950"/>
  </details>
</profile>
```

For deserializing the above with XMLSerializer in C#, how should I use attributes for this on my model class? The problem is the combination of an array with attributes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing XML File with multiple element attributes - attributes are not deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245846/deserializing-xml-file-with-multiple-element-attributes-attributes-are-not-des)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sample model class for direction

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "detail")]
    public class Detail
    {

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "unit")]
        public string Unit { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "details")]
    public class Details
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "detail")]
        public List<Detail> Detail { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "environment")]
        public string Environment { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "severity")]
        public string Severity { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "profile")]
    public class Profile
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "details")]
        public Details Details { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Although the XmlRoot attribute should only be applied one time in a document. Marking up the list with XmlElement works as needed.